# How do I implement geolocation in meteor with react

Tags: meteor, reactjs, geolocation

Pls. I want to implement geolocation in meteor with react. I do not completely understand how to do that. Meanwhile I have tried the code below, but without any result:

```
render() {
    if (Geolocation.latLng() == null) {
        return(
            <span>Determining locataion...</span>
        )
    } else {
        return Geolocation.latLng();
    }
    return(
        <div className="panel panel-default">
            <div className="panel-content">
                <div className="panel-heading">
                    Update Message
                </div>
                <form className="form center-block">
                    <input type="hidden" ref="imageid" />
                    <div className="panel-body">
<textarea id="sharing" placeholder="Share what?" ref="sharing"     className=" form-control input-lg">
                        </textarea>
                        <h3>I am here!</h3>
                        <div>
                        <span type="text"> {this.latLng.lat} </span>
                        </div>
                    </div> ....
```

I was not receiving any error message. Thus, I do not know how else to use geolocation inside react. Pls. I'm counting on your quickest help.

Comment: No body seemed to have solution to this problem. I am only asking for a clue to solve this.